# Bash: изменить цвет prompt в зависимости от exit status последней команды

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt

Я хочу визуализировать в консоли статус завершения последней команды.

Если последняя команда выполнилась со статусом 0, т. е. без ошибок, должен быть стандартный зеленый цвет. А если статус был не 0, то цвет должен быть красный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот на примере строка после `false` должна быть красная. Желательно еще вывести статус завершения, если он не 0.

Как это сделать?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B0_.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B2.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B0

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорим о **bash**, в оболочке есть встроенные переменные отвечающие за
настройки строки ввода.

- **PROMPT_COMMAND**
  Если установлена, значение воспринимается как команда выполняемая до выдачи основного приглашения командной строки (**$PS1**)
- **PS1**
  Основная переменная приглашения командной строки. Значение по умолчанию  `\s-\v\$`

Можно написать свою функцию и добавить в `~/.bashrc` файл. Разбив задачку на шаги получим:

`[статичный] [динамический] [станичный]`

```
_prmtcmd() {
    local EXIT="$?"

    local NA='\[\e[0m\]'
    local R='\[\e[0;31m\]'
    local G='\[\e[0;32m\]'
    local B='\[\e[1;34m\]'

    # Статичный: имя пользователя и хоста
    PS1="${G}\u@\h${NA}\n"

    # Динамический: выход из последней выполненной команды
    if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
        PS1+="[${R}false${NA}] "
    else
        PS1+="[${G}true${NA}] "
    fi

    # Статичный: приглашение к вводу
    PS1+="${B}~$ ${NA}"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=_prmtcmd
```

Графический пример выполнения:

[image: пример]

Смотрите модификаторы для каждого из цветов в документации (ссылки ниже).

**Ссылки**

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Variable-Index.html#Variable-Index
- http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting